# Transpose on an Access table

Tags: ms-access, transpose, ms-access-2013

I have a table that has checkbox columns (about 10-15) as shown below:

```
Race  |  Disability  |  Sexual Harrassment  |  ......  

Yes         No               Yes               
No          Yes              Yes
```

I wanted a query result with the totals like:

```
Basis   |           Total
Race                  1
Disability            1
Sexual Harrassment    2
```

I don't know how I can get different columns into one column, I'm guessing it is transpose, I'm not sure how to use it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a UNION query to unpivot your data, something like this

```sql
    SELECT 
        'Race' AS Basis,
        [Race] AS Response
    FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        'Disability' AS Basis,
        [Disability] AS Response
    FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        'Sexual Harrassment' AS Basis,
        [Sexual Harrassment] AS Response
    FROM YourTable
```

Save that query in Access as [MyDataUnpivoted] and then produce the sums like so

```sql
SELECT
    Basis,
    SUM(IIf(Response=True,1,0)) AS Total
FROM MyDataUnpivoted
GROUP BY Basis
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no easy way to go from columns to rows, usually people are trying to go from rows to columns.  The only way I can think to do this would be to loop through the Table collection and place the field names into an array, and then create a new table and write the contents of the array into it as records.

Comment: I guess you are right. But what I am ultimately trying to do is to make a pie chart with the types of cases. Can that be achieved?